# drawing text in canvas with set width and height in android

Tags: android, canvas, resize, drawing, drawtext

I need to draw a text onto the screen using a canvas. I want to use the canvas.drawText method but I don't know how to limit the space the text drawn to a confined width and height. The x and y position that are passed in the canvas.drawText are no problem to determine. I was thinking of recursively changing the font size until it fits within the bounds that I want. There is a problem with this though and that it can fit within the height size but not the width or vice versa. Isn't there a way to rescale the canvas.drawText so that it can fit within the width and height I want?